# how to wrap html into the value of a variable that holds a string?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

Suppose that I have a varialbe:

```
let display_text = "Cats are pawsome!"
```

I want to render it into:

```
<div>
  <b>Cats</b> are pawsome!
</div>
```

In other words, dynamically wrap the string "cats" wherever it appears.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if this is what you want to achieve. Have a look:

```js
let display_text = "Cats are pawsome!"
let display_text_html = display_text.replace('Cats', '<b>Cats</b>');

document.querySelector('.text-wrapper').innerHTML = display_text_html;
```

```html
<div class="text-wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: How do you get it to render as html?

Comment: Edited the answer, please check.

Comment: this will work for one cat and it's case sensitive

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?